# Using the Langrange Inversion Formula

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

*I am currently going through the proof of the Theorem $5.4.2$ on page 38 of Enumerative Combinatorics Vol $2$ by R. Stanley and I think I understand the proof. **The proof of Corollary $5.4.3$ as shown in the attached proof  is just a sketch and I am unable to prove it using the hint given**. All my reasoning does not lead me anywhere.
Could some please show me the proof? or perhaps a hint? I saw some proofs that strictly used the Cauchy-Residue Theorem but I want to avoid using this.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to say that this looks pretty clear to me. As Stanley says, for $H(x)=x^k$ this reduces to the previous theorem. In general if $H(x)=\sum h_k x^k$, then for a given $n$, the $x^n$ coefficient in $H(f(x))$ will depend only on finitely many of the $h_k$, so one can assume $H(x)$ is a polynomial etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little elaboration on Lord Shark the Unknown's comment.  Fix $n$ and $f$ and define an operator $T: K[[x]] \rightarrow K$ by

$$T(H) = n[x^n]H(f(x)) - [x^{n-1}]H'(x) G(x)^n.$$

We want to show $T(H) = 0$ for any $H$.  Note that $T(H) = 0$ when $H(x) = x^k$ for any $k$.  This is exactly the statement of Theorem 5.4.2.  Note also that this operator is *linear*.  You can show directly that $T(\alpha H_1 + \beta H_2) = \alpha T(H_1) + \beta T(H_2)$.

Thus $\ker T$ contains every polynomial. Now for any $H$, let $H_n$ be the truncation of $H$ to an $n$-th degree polynomial. Then $T(H) = T(H_n)$, since the $x^{n+1}$ or higher terms do not affect the coefficient of $x^n$ in $H(f(x))$ or the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $H'(x) G(x)^n$.  Since $H_n$ is a polynomial, it follows that $T(H_n) = 0$, and so $T(H) = 0$.